# What is the local python equivalent to import files from google.colab?

Tags: python, listdir

I am trying to replicate (on my local machine) part of this script [[PifuHD](https://colab.research.google.com/github/derekphilipau/machinelearningforartists/blob/main/PIFuHD_Demo.ipynb)

The script utilises the below code:

```
from google.colab import files
filename = list(files.upload().keys())[0]
```

I was unable to make it work and ended up trying to replicate it bit by bit. The key difference seems to be in the way it "reads" the filename.

`print(filename)` Outputs in the format of: myimage.png

When I try using the local install equivalent of os.listdir(mypath), it outputs in the format of: ['myimage.png']

My code:

```
path = 'pifuhd/sample_images'

filename = os.listdir(path)
print(filename)

try:
    image_path = 'pifuhd/sample_images/%s' % filename
except:
    image_path = 'pifuhd/sample_images/oldtest.png'

print(image_path)
```

It would seem this formatting is crucial to the script. In fact, it proceeds to call:

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

try:
  image_path = '/content/pifuhd/sample_images/%s' % filename
except:
  image_path = '/content/pifuhd/sample_images/test.png' # example image
```

The script outputs:
/content/pifuhd/sample_images/myimage.png

My local equivalent outputs:
/content/pifuhd/sample_images/['myimage.png']

This means that the rest of my script refuses to work as the input is in the incorrect format.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is os.listdir not the correct solution here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anything stop you from selecting 0th element from `os.listdir()`?

Comment: Like the comment above says, you could do `filename = os.listdir(path)[0]`, similar to the Colab notebook which does `filename = list(files.upload().keys())[0]`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work:

```
 File "/home/user/Code/newPifu/pifuhd/pifu.py", line 6, in <module>
    filename = os.listdir(path)[0]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pifuhd/sample_images'
```

Comment: What's your working directory? You can check with `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: print(os.getcwd) yields:
/home/user/Code/newPifu/np/bin/python /home/user/Code/newPifu/pifuhd/pifu.py

My file structure is:
/newPifu as the top level directory, containing both np (the venv) and pifuhd.

pifuhd contains /sample_images as a subfolder, and my script (pifu.py).

I'm relatively new to python but it would seem that the problem isn't really the cwd, as without the addition of [0], it can read the filename just fine - it's just not outputting it in the correct way.

Comment: *as without the addition of [0], it can read the filename just fine* Are you sure the cwd was the same before you added the `[0]`? Otherwise I don't know what to suggest, sorry!